# What are the downsides of booking separate departure and return flights?

Tags: air-travel, bookings

While I was browsing Google Flights, I noticed something that I haven't seen before. It said that if I booked the itinerary chosen, they'd be on separate tickets. This text was also in red, which I took as meaning it could be undesirable. I'm aware that this is risky for connecting flights, but is there any downside if they're both "one way" flights that are several days apart?

Comment: Thanks for the question!  The linked duplicate seems to address the issue well.  Welcome to Travel.SE.